# Marking certain days in date indexed pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got a dataframe which is date indexed (d-m-y). I wanted to create a binary feature column which denotes if a date is the second Saturday of the month.
What I've got so far is this:

```
def get_second_true(x):
    second = None
    for index, is_true in enumerate(x):
        if is_true and second is None:
            return index
        if is_true and second is not None:
            second = True

second_saturdays = df.groupby(['month', 'year']).apply(
    lambda x: x.index.weekday == 6
    ).apply(get_second_true)
```

I'm unable to get this back into a series which relates to the original dataframe's index in such a way that each row has a label of whether it is a second Saturday or not.

This feels like a common enough scenario, but I am unable to find the term used for doing such a thing. I've looked at `unstack` and `reset_index` but I don't understand them in enough depth to know if this can be done using them, or if multilevel indexing is even needed at all.

Comment: I thought that the R community might know what this is called since data frames are quiet common there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a special frequency in pandas like `WOM-2SUN` (Week-Of-Month: 2nd Sunday), so you can do it this way:

```
In [88]: df = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range('2000-01-01', periods=365)})

In [89]: df
Out[89]:
          date
0   2000-01-01
1   2000-01-02
2   2000-01-03
3   2000-01-04
4   2000-01-05
5   2000-01-06
6   2000-01-07
7   2000-01-08
8   2000-01-09
9   2000-01-10
..         ...
355 2000-12-21
356 2000-12-22
357 2000-12-23
358 2000-12-24
359 2000-12-25
360 2000-12-26
361 2000-12-27
362 2000-12-28
363 2000-12-29
364 2000-12-30

[365 rows x 1 columns]

In [90]: df.loc[df.date.isin(pd.date_range(start=df.date.min(), end=df.date.max(), freq='WOM-2SUN'))]
Out[90]:
          date
8   2000-01-09
43  2000-02-13
71  2000-03-12
99  2000-04-09
134 2000-05-14
162 2000-06-11
190 2000-07-09
225 2000-08-13
253 2000-09-10
281 2000-10-08
316 2000-11-12
344 2000-12-10
```

---

**UPDATE:** starting from Pandas 0.20.1 [the .ix indexer is deprecated, in favor of the more strict .iloc and .loc indexers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#deprecate-ix).

Answer (score 2):

The day is second Saturday of the month if weekday == 6 and day of the moth > 7 and day of the month <= 14

Comment: This solves my problem, thanks. I'd like to ask if there is a specific name for the type of operation I've defined. Say you want to mark the n'th occurrence of something in a grouped dataframe.